# Is there a way to check if a Google Compute Engine VM is ready to receive a http request from a firebase function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, http-error

I have a react app that want to send a file to a Google cloud compute VM instance, get it processed there, and then display it. This is currently working fine. To save money I want to start the instance with a http request from the react app, and turn it off when the computations are done. I start the instance with the following function, taken from the official [gce-documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-compute/blob/main/samples/startInstance.js)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');

async function startComputeEngine() {
    const instancesClient = new compute.InstancesClient();
    const [response] = await instancesClient.start({
        project: projectId,
        zone,
        instance: instanceName,
    });
    let operation = response.latestResponse;
    const operationsClient = new compute.ZoneOperationsClient();
    // Wait for the operation to complete.

    while (operation.status !== 'DONE') {
        operation = await operationsClient.wait({
            operation: operation.name,
            project: projectId,
            zone: operation.zone.split('/').pop(),
        });
        if (Array.isArray(operation)) {
            operation = operation[0]
        }
    }
    return "Success: Instance started"
}
```

This also works, and the VM instance is started correctly.

- When doing a HTTP-request to the VM-instance after this, I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. This is the same error I get if the VM is off.
- If I delay the http-request to the VM with ~30 seconds, I get another error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
- If I delay the HTTP-request with ~60 seconds it works as if should.

Even though the code to start the VM instance waits for the startup operation to be finished, it seems as it need additional time to boot up. Is there some way to detect when the HTTP-endpoint is  ready, preferably from within a firebase function?

Comment: What are the requirement of your VM? I mean, what are the blockers to use Cloud Run instead a VM?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, you can use vm custom [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata). In your vm instance, once http server started successfully you can store a flag `ServerRunning` as `true` in vm metadata

```
//This code block is part of the vm
app.listen(PORT, function() {
   //Set custom data here
})
```

[setMetaData](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata)

And in your cloud function you can create a polling function, that regularly calls vm metadata server and checks if `ServerRunning` exists and set to `true`. If exists, then cancel the polling function and execute the remaining code block.